# How to generate service reference for .netstandard 2

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-standard-2.0, svcutil.exe

We're migrating our codebase from .net framework to .net 7.  To do so, we're converting our infrastructure projects (domain objects, business layer, data layer) to .netstandard 2 so that we can use it in both the old and new versions of the front end web applications while they're being migrated.

I need to generate service references in one of the .netstandard projects but when I try to add a new service under Manage Connected Services, I get the following error.

```
MSBuild version 17.4.0+18d5aef85 for .NET
C:\Users\geoff\.nuget\packages\system.runtime.compilerservices.unsafe\6.0.0\buildTransitive\netcoreapp2.0\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.targets(4,5): error : System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe doesn't support netcoreapp2.0. Consider updating your TargetFramework to netcoreapp3.1 or later. [C:\Users\geoff\AppData\Local\Temp\WCFConnectedService\2023_Jan_31_15_49_26\svcutil_bootstrap\SvcutilBootstrapper\SvcutilBootstrapper.csproj]

Build FAILED.

C:\Users\geoff\.nuget\packages\system.runtime.compilerservices.unsafe\6.0.0\buildTransitive\netcoreapp2.0\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.targets(4,5): error : System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe doesn't support netcoreapp2.0. Consider updating your TargetFramework to netcoreapp3.1 or later. [C:\Users\geoff\AppData\Local\Temp\WCFConnectedService\2023_Jan_31_15_49_26\svcutil_bootstrap\SvcutilBootstrapper\SvcutilBootstrapper.csproj]
    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)
```

Any idea how I can get this working with the current .netstandard 2 setup?

Comment: Are you referencing the `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe` package? Try using `ExcludeAssets="all"` on it: `<PackageReference Include="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" Version="6.0.0" ExcludeAssets="all" />`.

Comment: No we are not referencing that package.